# Centos 7 Created service to run shell script on infinite loop

Tags: bash, service, centos

I have the following script:

```
whie true
do
  #code
sleep 60
done
```

I then wanted to create a service to start the machine and launch this script as service:
created my.service  at /etc/systemd/system/my.service

```
[Unit]
Description=my Script

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

problem occurs when i systemctl start my.service

it goes to while true loop and hang in there, how can i run this service and make it run in the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to systemd specification at [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). `Type=forking` is not exactly correct kind of start-up in your case

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with
> ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent
> process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all
> communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the
> main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit
> started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of
> traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended
> to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify
> the main process of the service. systemd will proceed with starting
> follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

The `Type=simple` can be correct one. You can try with it

> If set to simple (the default if ExecStart= is specified but neither
> Type= nor BusName= are), the service manager will consider the unit
> started immediately after the main service process has been forked
> off. It is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= is the
> main process of the service. In this mode, if the process offers
> functionality to other processes on the system, its communication
> channels should be installed before the service is started up (e.g.
> sockets set up by systemd, via socket activation), as the service
> manager will immediately proceed starting follow-up units, right after
> creating the main service process, and before executing the service's
> binary. Note that this means systemctl start command lines for simple
> services will report success even if the service's binary cannot be
> invoked successfully (for example because the selected User= doesn't
> exist, or the service binary is missing).